# Chromium repository on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, chrome

I want to install Chromium on Fedora 23. To my knowledge, there are two available copr repositories:

- https://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/spot/chromium/
- https://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/churchyard/chromium-russianfedora-tested/

Is there some major difference i should be aware of between these two?

EDIT: Update 2nd link to tested release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner of the first copr repository is a Redhat-employee [working](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1270322) towards getting chromium into the official repositories. The work has only started a couple weeks ago, as Fedora [weakened](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2015-September/214262.html) some of their packaging guidelines to allow selected packages to bundle their own libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are unofficial repositories for Fedora. There is nothing you can not read from the description on the links:

The first one is

> "stable" branch builds

The second one

> haven't been tested.

But there is [alternative repo](https://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/churchyard/chromium-russianfedora-tested/) to the second one with appendix "tested", which should generally work better and has also newer build.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've posted a wrong link to the second repo. There is no official release for Fedora?

Comment: No, so far there is no official release, because of packaging guidelines were quite strict. This has changed and now, there is ongoing work on the `chromium` to be in official repository, as stated in the other answer. But it will take some time.